# THREAD WARNING: ['InAppBrowser'] took '175.479736' ms. Plugin should use a background thread

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an issue on using InAppBrowser in ionic. My application developed by using ionic1 and Cordova plugin. I have installed `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` and injected in my controller and have used below code

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {


                var options = {
                  location: 'yes',
                  clearcache: 'yes',
                  toolbar: 'yes',
                  closebuttoncaption: 'DONE?'
                };
$cordovaInAppBrowser.open($scope.submiturl, '_blank', options)
      .then(function(event) {
        // success
      })
      .catch(function(event) {
        // error
      });
});
```

Error report shows,

```
THREAD WARNING: ['InAppBrowser'] took '175.479736' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
```

This above code is working fine in android but it shows error in ios. Please help anyone to fix this issue. I'm opening payment gateway url on this link. I could not find out the solution even after lot of R&D.

Comment: Thats just a warning, no worries.

Comment: I thought like this is simple warning but only white screen comes to display, not showing actual screen

Comment: Then theres probably a problem somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Yes having an issue on URL. In ios in-app browser couldn't use array data in query string. I have used like this url http://www.url?firstname=Vinoth&lastname=&phone=852642399&amount=1000&productinfo=JSA&email=rvk995@gmail.com&pg=NB&bankcode=BOIB&pay_arr=[{"scheme_type":"0","amount":1000,"pay_amt":1000,"charge":"0.00","charge_head":"Convenience fee","firstname":"Vinoth","lastname":"","Zipcode":"","email":"rvk1995@gmail.com","phone":"852642399","productinfo":"JSA","udf1":"3637","udf2":"","udf3":"","udf4":"","udf5":"","discount":"","chit_number":"JSA Not Allocated"}]

Answer (score 0):

As David said, this is just a warning. Cordova iOS triggers this warning when a call to a plugin blocks for more than 10ms. If this delay is not acceptable, to fix it you'll have to make changes to the inappbrowser plugin to make [this method](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/src/ios/CDVInAppBrowser.m#L80) asynchronous.